# Let $X$ be a metric space and let $r>0$. Then either there is a countable collection of balls of radius $r$ that covers $X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The full theorem is:
Let $X$ be a metric space and let $r>0$. Then either there is a countable collection of balls of radius $r$ that covers $X$, or there is an uncountable collection of disjoint balls in $X$ of radius $r/2$.

The professor suggested that we might need Zorn's Lemma to prove this theorem, but I had no idea, and I want to know what this theorem wants to show in geometry.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea behind this problem is the following: Let $d$ denote the metric on $X$ and let $B(x,c):=\{y \in X: d(y,x) < c\}$ (the open ball with center $x \in X$ and radius $c>0$). Fix $r >0$ and let $Z \subseteq X$ be such that
${\cal C}:=\{B(z,r/2): z \in Z\}$ is a collection of balls such that

1. $z_1,z_2 \in Z$, $z_1 \not= z_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $B(z_1,r/2) \cap B(z_2,r/2)= \emptyset$,
2. ${\cal C}$ is maximal in the sense that adding any ball $B(x,r/2)$ for some $x \notin Z$ leads to $B(z_0,r/2) \cap B(x,r/2) \not= \emptyset$ for some $z_0 \in Z$.

The existence of such a maximal collection can be proved by Zorn's Lemma by ordering the set of all collections with property 1. by inclusion. Now given such a maximal collection you can show that
$$
X=U:=\bigcup_{z \in Z} B(z,r),
$$
since if $x \in X$ there are two cases: If $x \in Z$ then $x \in U$, trivially. If $x \in X \setminus Z$ then $B(z_0,r/2) \cap B(x,r/2) \not= \emptyset$ for some $z_0 \in Z$. Let $y \in B(z_0,r/2) \cap B(x,r/2)$. Then
$$
d(x,z_0) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z_0)< r/2 + r/2 = r,
$$
that is $x \in B(z_0,r)$. Hence $x \in U$. Thus $\{B(z,r): z \in Z\}$ covers $X$. If there is no countable collection of balls of radius $r$ that covers $X$ then $Z$ and with that too ${\cal C}$ is uncountable.

Answer (score -1):

If you assume Ball of radius $N < \infty$ is compact in $X$ and distance between any pair of points is finite in $X$ then $X$ can be covered by a countable collection of balls of radius $r$. Here is the proof: Take $N$ an integer, take Ball of radius $N$, $B_N$ in X centered around some fixed point $x$. Then by compactness this $B_N$ can be covered by a finite collection $B_N(x) = \cup_{i = 1}^{r(N)} B_r(x_i)$. Now form a set $S_N = \{x_1,...,x_{r(N)}\}$. then as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the total collection of such sets $X = \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} B_N(x) = \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \cup_{i = 1}^{r(N)} B_r(x_i)$ is a cover for $X$ with a countable collection of sets since $\cup_{N=1}^{\infty} S_N$ is countable as it is a countable union of countable sets. So now the problem is now reduced to the case, when $B_N(x)$ is not compact or distance between some pair of points is $\infty$. I dont think latter is an interesting case. So consider when $B_N$ is not compact and complete the proof.
A case where $B_N$ with $N>(r+1)$ is not compact: Take some uncountable collection of points $X$. Define $d(x,y) = r+1$ if $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y$. This is a metric and with this metric $B_N(x)$ is not compact as $B_N(x) = X$ (full space) and $B_r(x)$ contains only a singleton i.e., $B_r(x) = \{x\}$

Comment: This is not an answer as it does not cover all cases, and there are plenty of metric spaces whose closed balls are not compact. They are of interest although you do not seem to think so

Comment: Hi man. The question just wants to understand the geometry. I think my answer explained the geometry of the problem. Apology if its not complete.

Comment: I understand your point. But I don't think this explains the geometric philosophy hidden behind this result in any way. This explains how a proof would work in some simple cases.